# EJB invoke a method which later invoke another EJB -> return null

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have a structure like this

```
@Stateless
public class CoreMainEJB implements CoreMainEJBRemote, CoreMainEJBLocal {

    @Override
    public void process(String configFileName) throws Exception {
         ...
         PackageProcessor p = new PackageProcessor();
         p.processPackage(Object something); 
    }
}
```

then in `PackageProcesor.java` -> is not annotate `@Stateless`

```
public class PackageProcessor(){
    @EJB
    private GenericEJB genericEJB;

    public void processPackage(Object something){
        genericEJB.create(something);

    }
    ...
}
```

The injection of `GenericEJB` return null. Here is the content of GenericEJB

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class GenericEJB{
     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "someWebPUnit")
     private EntityManager em;

     public void create(Object t){
         em.persist(t);
     }
}
```

Any idea why the injection of `GenericEJB` return null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an object like this:

```
PackageProcessor p = new PackageProcessor()
```

the EJB container does not know anything about it, the container does not manage the lifecycle of this object, it also cannot inject anything, wrap it in aspects, apply transaction behavior. Simply put: for you application server this object does not exist.

Of course if you annotate `PackageProcessor` with `@Stateless` and inject it as ordinary EJB, it will work. Any reasons why you don't want to do this?

Comment: Is it a bad idea to have many EJB? Because if I did what you said, I might end up with 5-6 EJB. Is it bad in term of performance? Compare to putting these method in the same EJB? I guess what I am asking is does EJB inject impact the performance? does 5-6 EJB make the project much more heavy weight?

Comment: :-). I can imagine projects with hundreds or even thousands of EJBs... Dependency injection has only impact on initialization time, when the bean is first created. They are typically pooled afterwards. Also, don't bother about performance when few lines later you will access database or JMS queue...

Comment: Also, in EJB injection of stateless session beans can be very cheap as the container only has to inject a kind of URL (proxy) to the session bean, not an actual instance.